# Centre a form and its labels in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple form with two fields, Username and password and a Log in buttion which use CSS. 
I am trying to centre the form and its labels. current it centres the field boxes but not the labels, it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zkzh66n0/

I think its something to do with the other CSS styles because when I tried the style on its own in fiddle it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/zkzh66n0/1/

HTML:

```
<div id ="form">

       <form action = "entryformlogon.php" method="post">


        <label for = "user">Username</label>
            <input type ="text" name ="Username"><br>

        <label for ="password">Password</label> 
            <input type ="password" name = "Password"><br>

        <input type = "submit" name ="loginbutton" value ="Log in">

    </form>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
label{
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
}

input, textarea{
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


#loginbutton{
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 90px;
}

#form {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You have to remove `float: left;` from label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `float: left` with `display: inline-block`, then the width and margin work. Also, if you want to refer to the loginbutton via `#loginbutton`, you have to set its `id` attribute in addition to the name, because that is what this selector refers to.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkzh66n0/8/)

The relevant CSS:

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
}

#loginbutton{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 28px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

I also changed the buttons CSS to include `display: inline-block` so the margin can be set so it lines up with the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/zkzh66n0/2/

remove `float: left;` from label.

if you need space in labels and input box try to give `padding` like below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zkzh66n0/3/

Comment: @  Charley Baker - you need to tick it as a answer, if it is working for you

Comment: @CharleyBaker - Use `label { display: inline-block; width: 120px; }` to line your labels up.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa - No one needs to tick anything. Accepting an answer is **optional**, though encouraged with an answer that solves the problem the best.